# "The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

Tags: sql-server, date

I have a stored procedure causing a date conversion error. I don't know what changed as it's been working fine for many months but our development group is downstream of a national DW. There are two variables used to retrieve date range `@DatePlus1` & `@DayOffset`.

`@DatePlus1` is used in a dozen or so CTEs that I won't post unless asked for but I commented out the date calculation and hard set the date as '2017-10-31 00:00:00' and ran the procedure. It ran without error but I don't understand why.

The original code set the `@DatePlus1` as `Date` type which generated same error in subject.

```
SELECT @DayOffset = ISNULL(@DayOffset, 0)

DECLARE @DatePlus1 DATETIME2(0)  --Was date but changed to datetime2 while troubleshooting

SELECT
     @DatePlus1 = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(dd, 1, DATEADD(dd, @DayOffset, GETDATE())))
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your question that you've eliminated the too-obvious possibility that your incoming data now has a datetime2 value that is out of range for a smalldatetime datatype.

Comment: @Tab Alleman I'm trying to understand the difference between passing a datetime2 variable as opposed to passing '2017-10-31 00:00:00' in a where clause.  Why does it work when passing the set value?

You're right though.  I'm sure a change was made to metadata somewhere that I don't know about but there are literally dozens of CTEs in subqueries which literally makes it like hunting the needle in the haystack.

Comment: Why do you think the problem is programmatic or meta-data related?  It sounds to me like a data issue.   If you've ruled out data issues, how?   Can you provide us with a script that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I replaced all occurrences of variable DatePlus1 with '2017-10-31 00:00:00' in the stored procedure and ran the SP and it runs fine.  The DatePlus1 variable is used in the WHERE clauses where it compares RequestDate or ActivityDate from different tables.  So why does run fine when I replace the variable with a static value but errs when variable is used in WHERE conditions.

I'm going through now and putting DatePlus1 back in WHERE clause 1 at a time.  So far I've done 2 and it fails on 1 RequestDate comparison but not another but RequestDate appears in different tables.

Comment: You're not understanding me.  Your script starts with `SELECT @DayOffset = ISNULL(@DayOffset, 0)`.  Where did `DayOffset` get declared?   What value did it have before that first line?   What happens if you replace all occurrences of DatePlus1 with '1701-01-01 00:00:00'?   What is the value inside @DatePlus1 when it errors?

Comment: I thought I was clear at least twice.  The date calculation was the same DayOffset is an integer and this case had value of 0.  I only posted relevant piece of code and not the declartion of DayOffset.  If I manually run the date calculation and then replace DatePlus1 with that static value in all WHERE clause and then run, it runs fine.

I'm not sure you understand that I'm asking why a static value is being interpreted differently than a variable in a WHERE clause when the variable would have the same value as the static value.

Comment: In your *actual* code, are you using `GETDATE()`?  Or is it *actually* derived from somewhere else that you aren't showing us, such as a table column or another variable?  In most cases, the value that is causing the problem is something like `0001-01-01 00:00:00`  (such as derived from `DateTime.MinValue` in .net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A static value would NOT be interpreted any differently than the same value passed in a variable.   Therefore the problem is not what you think it is.

You are testing with a static variable that is in-range for a `smalldatetime` datatype.  And your test is successful.

Therefore the reason your test fails when you use a variable is because the value of the variable is out-of-range for a `smalldatetime`, OR results in some selection of a value that is out-of-range.

The problem is not that you are using a variable.   The problem is that you are giving that variable an invalid value in some part of the code that you are not showing in your question.

To troubleshoot this, you need to find all the places in your code where you populate a `smalldatetime` variable or column, and use `PRINT` or `SELECT` statements to see what value you are trying to insert into the `smalldatetime`.

> So far I've done 2 and it fails on 1 RequestDate comparison but not another but RequestDate appears in different tables.

So another thing to look for is places in your code where the value of your variable could get changed programmatically.   I would look right between the two queries where the comparison works, and the one where it fails.

Comment: I'm not sure why someone voted down my question but I'm going to mark this response as answer because actually answered my question which was more about how a static date is treated versus variable however, it turns out the error SQL returned doesn't appear to have anything to do with the problem.  I isolated the chunk of code causing the error and ran it independently and it ran fine with variable and with static value however, when running in SSMS it ran out of memory so sent output to file and 38 million rows returned.  I sent back to developer to filter down with suggestions.